# Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Tags: retain

I'm verifying my app and I got a lot of this kind of warnings:

Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

This is an example of one of those methods that generate the warning (the warning is on the return line)

```
+ (vehicleInfo*) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node
{
    if(node == nil) { return nil; }
    return (vehicleInfo*)[[[vehicleInfo alloc] initWithNode: node] autorelease];
}
```

Is it something I should worry about?
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the warning because you're violating the contract that you become an owner of objects created with a method named with `new`.  Any code calling `+newWithNode` expects to be an owner of the return value and should later call `-release` to release it.

See the [Objective-C Memory Management Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for more details.

Comment: Following your link, the guide say:

Answer (score -1):

Following you link, the guide says:

**Use autorelease to Send a Deferred release**

You use autorelease when you need to send a deferred release message—typically when returning an object from a method. For example, you could implement the fullName method like this:

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
     NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                                      self.firstName, self.lastName] autorelease];
     return string;
}
```

You own the string returned by alloc. To abide by the memory management rules, you must relinquish ownership of the string before you lose the reference to it. If you use release, however, the string will be deallocated before it is returned (and the method would return an invalid object). Using autorelease, you signify that you want to relinquish ownership, but you allow the caller of the method to use the returned string before it is deallocated.

So, despite the warning, it seems I'm doing the right stuff, don't I?

Comment: This is not an answer, please don't respond like this—edit your question or ask a new question.  In any case, no, you're not doing stuff right: your method name `newWithNode:` implies that the caller will own the returned object, but because you're autoreleasing the return value, the caller does not become an owner, so you're violating the convention.